# Network graph: Given a network of n nodes, how to assign each node exactly r bidirectional connections?

Tags: graph-theory, network

I am a bit ashamed to ask this question. I work as a programmer, but my math is horribly bad.

It's not a programming question, as it's more related to graphs than actual code, that's why I decided to not ask in stackoverflow.com

I assume this should be trivial for people in here...?

Given a network of n nodes, is it possible to assign exactly r connections to each node, if each connection is bidirectional?

For example, in a 8 nodes network, have each node to have exactly 4 bidirectional connections? The closest I got for this example is 7 nodes with each 4 connections, but 1 node has 2.

My intuition tells me that there is some formula where for a number `n` there is a minimum `r` for which this is possible. In the example above, maybe `n=8` nodes doesn't work for `r=4`, but maybe it works for `n=16`...

I hope my question makes sense and someone can help me here. Thanks.

Comment: A cube, together with the four body diagonals, has eight nodes, each with four connections. The general question is covered by the term, *graphical sequence*. Look that up, it should have what you want.

Comment: Thank you, I will